# what widget we give to URLFIELD in django

Tags: django, django-forms

what widget we give to URLField in forms django i wanna set placeholer and some class to input

```
link = forms.URLField(widget=forms.????)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [documentation on a **`URLField`** says [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#urlfield):

> - Default widget: [**`URLInput`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.URLInput)

You thus can use a [**`URLInput`** widget [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.URLInput) for that:

```
link = forms.URLField(widget=forms.URLInput())
```